# flex row not expanding

Tags: html, css

I have a flex row in a flex column container, and it does not expand properly to the size of its children, but compresses to '*fit*' in the parent.

Html

```
<div class="content">
  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

[In this example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KeLAu), you can see that the `ul` does not take the space it needs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer, I am not sure it is the correct way to do it.

`float: left;` on the `ul` element will enable to ignore the parent's width. However, since the parent is a flex container, the `float` property of its children will be ignored. Therefore one should add a div around the `ul` element.

[Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/nsaoI) is a working example.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of confused on what you are asking. However, if you are just wanting to make each li tag fit an entire page, you can just add the justify-content attribute to your ul like so.Justify-content aligns things based on its x axis.

```
.content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

I would suggest checking out this page: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

It help me a lot when it came to learning about flexbox :)